# Prove that given $a,b,c > 0$, it is possible to construct a triangle with sides of length $a,b,c$ if and only if $pa^2+qb^2 > pqc^2$

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

> Prove that given $a,b,c > 0$, it is possible to construct a triangle with sides of length $a,b,c$ if and only if $pa^2+qb^2 > pqc^2$ for any $p,q$ with $p+q = 1$.

Should I prove this using the triangle inequality? Also should I split the proof up into two parts for the if and only if?

Comment: How you write down the proof depends on your style and on what makes it more readable. As for your other question: did you actually try to prove this with the triangular inequality? Did you try something else?

Answer (score 6):

Below is a complete solution.  Don't look at it if you want to solve this problem by yourself.  Also, yes, the Triangle Inequality is definitely required in this problem.

---

> Assume that $a,b,c>0$ satisfy the condition that $pa^2+qb^2>pqc^2$ for any $p,q \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $p+q=1$.  Choosing $p$ and $q$ to be $\frac{b}{a+b}$ and $\frac{a}{a+b}$, respectively, we obtain $c<a+b$.  Choosing $p$ and $q$ to be $\frac{b}{b-a}$ and $\frac{a}{a-b}$, respectively, we obtain $c>|a-b|$, which implies $a<b+c$ and $b<c+a$.  Ergo, $a$, $b$, and $c$ form a triangle.

---

> Conversely, suppose that $a,b,c>0$ form a triangle.  Let $p,q\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that $p+q=1$.  If $p=0$ or $q=0$, then the inequality $pa^2+qb^2>pqc^2$ holds trivially.  Now, suppose that $p,q>0$.  Then, by the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, $$\frac{a^2}{q}+\frac{b^2}{p}=\left(\frac{a^2}{q}+\frac{b^2}{p}\right)(q+p)\geq (a+b)^2>c^2\,,$$ whence $pa^2+qb^2>pqc^2$ holds.  If $p>0$ and $q<0$, then we note by symmetry that $\frac{1}{1-q}a^2+\frac{-q}{1-q}c^2>\frac{(-q)}{(1-q)^2}b^2$, which gives $$pa^2-pqc^2>\frac{p(-q)}{1-q}b^2=-qb^2\,,$$ as $p=1-q$.  The previous inequality is precisely $pa^2+qb^2>pqc^2$.  If $p<0$ and $q>0$, we can prove the inequality $pa^2+qb^2>pqc^2$ in a similar manner.

Comment: You must show for any choices of $p$ and $q$ that it will form a triangle. You just showed that for a particular example it is true, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "we note by symmetry"? Could you motivate that inequality a bit more?

Comment: Exchange the roles of $b$ and $c$.

Comment: @JacobWillis No. In the "if" part you have to prove that **if** $pa^2 + qb^2 > pqc^2$ for every choice of $p,q \in \Bbb{R}$ with $p+q=1$, **then** segments of length $a,b,c$ can form a triangle. In your comment you are actually asking to prove that **if** $pa^2 + qb^2 > pqc^2$ for some given $p,q \in \Bbb{R}$ with $p+q=1$, **then** segments of length $a,b,c$ can form a triangle, which is *quite stronger*.

Comment: I made a little mistake, which is fixed now.  So, you have $ra^2+sb^2>rsc^2$ if $r,s>0$ and $r+s=1$.  Exchanging $b$ and $c$, you get $ra^2+sc^2>rsb^2$ for $r,s>0$ and $r+s=1$.  Now, replace $r$ by $1/(1-q)$ and $s$ by $-q/(1-q)$.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, although the spoilers are a bit annoying. Interestingly, it looks like in the second part the "triangle" hypothesis is needed only when $p,q > 0$.

Comment: No, $p$ and $q$ being negative is very important.  This is a version of the OP's statement if $p,q\geq 0$: for $a,b,c>0$, $a+b>c$ if and only if $pa^2+qb^2>pqc^2$ for every $p,q\geq 0$ such that $p+q=1$.

Comment: I hid my solution because I got the impression that the OP was merely asking about what would be the best way to write his proof, and not really seeking a proof.

Comment: My bad. The use of the triangle hypothesis in the cases $p < 0$ and $q < 0$ is hidden in the "by symmetry" statement.

Comment: @A.P. Still, the solution here seems to just show that for a particular example.

Comment: @JacobWillis Only in the second part *showing* is needed, and it is done. In the first part we simply *assume* that the inequality holds for every possible choice of $p,q$. The nice thing is that we don't *need* every choice to prove that the three lengths can form a triangle: we only need two choices to derive the three inequalities we need.

Answer (score 0):

$\Rightarrow$ We will consider triangle $OAB$ wher $A,\ B$ are
vectors on $\mathbb{R}^2$ Define $$a=|A|,\ b=|B|,\ c=|A-B|$$ Then
$$ |A|^2+|B|^2-2A\cdot B=|A-B|^2 $$

Then $pA+qB,\ p+q=1$ is in a line passing through $A,\ B$. Then
\begin{align} |pA+qB|^2&=p^2a^2+q^2b^2+2pqA\cdot B \\&=
p^2a^2+q^2b^2+pq (a^2+b^2-c^2)
\\& =pa^2+ qb^2 -pqc^2 \ \ast\end{align}

Since $a,\ b>0$, so $|pA+qB|>0$ Hence "only if" is proved

$\Leftarrow$ In $\ast$, $$pa^2+ qb^2 -pqc^2=(pa)^2+ (qb)^2-2(pa)(pb)
C $$ where $$ C= - \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab }$$

If $C>1$ then $c>a+b $ So for $pa=qb$ we have $pa^2+qb^2
> pqc^2>pq(a+b)^2\Rightarrow (pa-qb)^2>0 $ It is a contradiction

If $C<-1$ then $|a-b|>c$ If $a>b$ then $a>b+c$ so that for $ p=-t,\
t>0,\ q=1+t$ we have $ (b-tc)^2>0$ Let $t=\frac{b}{c}$ Hence it is a
contradiction

So $|C|\leq 1$ So we have $\theta$ s.t. $\cos\ \theta=-C$ If we have
triangle of sides $a,\ b,\ c'$ where $\theta$ is an angle between
sides of length $a,\ b$, then $\cos\ \theta=(a^2+b^2-(c')^2)/2ab$
That is $c=c'$ This complete the proof